# Sort value like "number/number/number: in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `/` delimited numeric data as string, similar to date strings, like:

```
('95/05/13'), ('900/04/15'), ('89/05/15'), ('189/07/15')
```

I need to `ORDER BY` year first (third part) then month (second part) and at the end day/number (first part) in this order:

```
('189/07/15'), ('89/05/15'), ('900/04/15'), ('95/05/13')
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I tried:

```
CASE 
    WHEN PatIndex('%[/]%',invoiceid) > 0
      THEN LEFT(invoiceid, PatIndex('%[/]%', invoiceid) - 1)
      ELSE invoiceid 
END * 1 DESC,
CASE 
    WHEN PatIndex('%[/]%',REVERSE(invoiceid)) > 0
      THEN RIGHT(invoiceid, PatIndex('%[/]%', REVERSE(invoiceid)) - 1)
      ELSE NULL 
END * 1 DESC
```

but it only gives me results based on first number.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a6cb/1)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results  Also, tag the question with the database you are actually using.  By the way, SQL has no keywords called `SORT BY`.

Comment: You probably mean `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using SQL Server, you can use something like

```
select * from [YourTable]
order by PARSENAME(REPLACE([YourColumn], '/', '.'), 1) desc, 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE([YourColumn], '/', '.'), 2) desc, 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE([YourColumn], '/', '.'), 3) desc
```

**Update:**
This I just ran in your fiddle (SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT invoiceid FROM Invoice
ORDER BY PARSENAME(REPLACE([invoiceid], '/', '.'), 1) desc, 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE([invoiceid], '/', '.'), 2) desc, 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE([invoiceid], '/', '.'), 3) desc
```

[PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188006(v=sql.100).aspx) is supposed to be used to parse object name and retrieve server name, db name etc. But, basically what it does is, it splits by '.' and gives the parts in reverse order (last part...first part). And it can split upto four parts only!

Here what I have done is, replaced the '/'s with '.'s, and then used parsename to split the string. e.g. 123/45/678 => 123.45.678 => 678, 45, 123. Then I have used those parts to order the results as required! (This is not the cleanest solution possible, but works fine for this limited requirements.)